# Best way to run a function only after two concurrent process ends?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mvp

I have several concurrent processes which finish at varying times, I would like to run a function only after all of those processes end.

I have thought of the following solution, but it isn't exactly clean.

```
process1_onSuccess(){
 process1_finished = true;
 hasProcessesFinished()
}

process2_onSuccess(){
 process2_finished = true;
 hasProcessesFinished()
}

hasProcessesFinished(){
 if(process1_finished && process2_finished){
//Do something
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should look into `CompletableFuture`.

For example, you can do:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = Arrays.a
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("First finished!");
        }),
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Second finished!");
        }));

completableFutures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
System.out.println("Both done. Doing something else");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with coroutines in Kotlin, where you can launch multiple jobs within the same context and register a function to be invoked when all are finished.

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
    launch {
        Log.d("CoroutineJob", "delay 2500 started")
        delay(2500)
        Log.d("CoroutineJob", "delay 2500 finished")
    }
    launch {
        Log.d("CoroutineJob", "delay 1000 started")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("CoroutineJob", "delay 1000 finished")
    }
}.invokeOnCompletion {
    Log.d("CoroutineJob", "all jobs completed")
}
```

The inner `launch` will be children of the outer, and `invokeOnCompletion` runs when all children are finished. The code above produces the following logcat:

```
D/CoroutineJob: delay 2500 started
D/CoroutineJob: delay 1000 started
D/CoroutineJob: delay 1000 finished
D/CoroutineJob: delay 2500 finished
D/CoroutineJob: all jobs completed
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it can be done with coroutines if you need to avoid blocking the main thread, and your function that runs after the work is finished must also be run on the main thread.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    listOf(
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) { doProcess1() },
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) { doProcess2() }
    ).joinAll()
    doPostProcess()
}
```

If working with the UI in a fragment, replace `lifecycleScope` with `viewLifecycleScope`. If in a ViewModel, replace it with `viewModelScope`.